# In Android how can i create a folder in system launcher and put apps in it?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am creating an app that requires creating a folder in launcher . I tried to make it but it didn't work .In Android how can i create a folder in system launcher and put apps in it ?

Comment: Right click at res folder then go to option new then Folder . Folder will create at inside of res folder it's depends on you where you want to create folder

Comment: i mean create a fold in home screen.put the apps icon in the fold.i can lanuch from this

Comment: i can not understend what your mean please add some more how you are trying to do it so add some more code here defiantly we will help you ...

Comment: There are ~1.5 billion Android devices in use, spanning thousands of device models. Those have hundreds of launcher implementations pre-installed, and there are hundreds (perhaps thousands) more launcher apps available via the Play Store and elsewhere. None of them have to have folders. None of them have to have an API that allow third-party apps to work with folders.

Comment: I mean I want make an application ,it can create a folder in home screen ,and this folder can put the other apps in it( the icons) .i can lanuch the app from the icon

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok, that's easy.

Just make your launcher icon look like a folder with other icons inside.

And when someone launches your app, launch an activity dialog, or a simple transparent activity, that looks like a folder but that is [transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android), so it gives the illusion that you're still within the launcher.

It will also be super important [how](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/) you make your activity transparent to make sure there is no glitch at the beginning of its launch otherwise the illusion won't hold.